# Serialize Java List to XML using Jackson XML mapper

Tags: java, xml, jackson, pojo, xmlmapper

Hi I need to create an XML from JAVA using Jackson-dataformat XMLMapper.
The XML should be like

```
<Customer>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Mighty Pulpo</name>
    <addresses>
      <city>austin</city>
      <state>TX</state>
    </addresses>
    <addresses>
      <city>Hong Kong</city>
      <state>Hong Kong</state>
    </addresses>
</Customer>
```

But I get it always like with an extra "< addresses> < /addresses>" tag.

```
<Customer>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Mighty Pulpo</name>
<addresses>
    <addresses>
      <city>austin</city>
      <state>TX</state>
    </addresses>
    <addresses>
      <city>Hong Kong</city>
      <state>Hong Kong</state>
    </addresses>
<addresses>
</Customer>
```

I am using below code to create XML

```
JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbAnnotationModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.registerModule(jaxbAnnotationModule);
mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(customer);
System.out.println(xml);
```

Please can some one help me? How can I remove the extra tag please. I have tried to use  @XmlElement but it does not help help. TIA!!

Comment: You are having list of address(Multiple) in customer class. so you need to have parent node addresses and its child node will be adress.

Comment: Thx Manoj, but I do not want any parental node. Can we somehow omit the parental node?

Comment: I got the answer - Just need to use  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) Thx for spending time to read it.

Comment: real question is how to get back. good luck with that.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try the below code

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "customer") 
class Customer {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id")
    private int id;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    private String  name;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "addresses")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private Address[] address;

    // you can add it on getter method instead of declaration.  
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public Address[] getAddress(){ 
        return address;
   }

   //getters, setters, toString             
}

class Address {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "city")
    private String city;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "state")
    private String state;
    // getter/setter 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This setting changes default wrapping behavior, if you don't want to deal with annotation everywhere in your code.

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, atleast on version 2.15.2 of Jackson.

Comment: @Sandeep In newer versions, you can use `XmlMapper mapper = XmlMapper.builder().defaultUseWrapper(false).build()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to ManojP's answer, if adding the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` on the declaration of your variable doesn't work (which was the case for me), adding it to the getter method will do the trick.