# spring boot XML is populating extra tags

Tags: xml, spring-boot, jackson

I am new to springboot and following some tutorials like java brains.  i am trying to create a XML for employees but My Spring Boot application is returning additional tag. 
I have added Jackson-dataformat-xml in pom. 
Please help.Thank in advance.

Expecting:

```
<Employees>
<Employee>
<id>1</id>
<name>Topic1</name>
<department>Description1</department>
</Employee>
</Employees>
```

Actual Result:

```
<Employees>
<employees>
<employees>
<id>1</id>
<name>Topic1</name>
<department>Description1</department>
</employees>
</employees>
</Employees>
```

Employees Class

```
public class Employees {

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public Employees(List<Employee> employees) {
        super();
        this.employees = employees;
    }


}
```

Employee Class:

```
public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public Employee(int id, String name, String department) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", produces = "application/xml")
    public Employees getAllEmployees() {
        List<Employee> controllerEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        controllerEmployee.add(new Employee(1,"Topic1","Description1"));

        Employees employees = new Employees(controllerEmployee);

        return employees;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can follow the below stack overflow link to resolve the issue,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580797/spring-boot-rest-api-returning-a-list-array-formatting-issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following annotation, @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) in your Employees class as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580797/spring-boot-rest-api-returning-a-list-array-formatting-issue)

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Employees {

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Employee")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private List<Employee> employees;

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}

public Employees(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}

}
```

And here is the response that you get after making the code changes,

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>Employee1</name>
   <department>Dev</department>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
   <id>2</id>
   <name>Employee2</name>
   <department>QA</department>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```